# The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values - Angular 2 & Spring MVC

Tags: spring, angular, spring-mvc, filter, cors

I'm working on multiple angular clients consuming the same Restful apis, from different domain names, i made the configuration at server side, and it worked when there was one client, but after adapting the **CorsFilter** Component, my angular clients throw this message.

**The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values**

```
    public class CorsFilter implements Filter {

        public CorsFilter() {
        }

        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
                throws IOException, ServletException {

            HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) res;

            httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:5200, http://localhost:4200");
            httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
            httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
            httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            httpResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "4800");

            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }

        @Override
        public void destroy() {
        }

        @Override
        public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
        }

    }
```

**Ajax call from angular 2 Service**

```
  login(form) {
    var objectToSend = "j_username="+form.j_username+"&j_password="+form.j_password;
    let headers = new Headers(
      {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' ,
      }
    );
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers ,withCredentials : true});
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/**/authenticate', objectToSend,options)
      .map((res) => res)
      .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.text() || 'Server error' ));
  }
```

Comment: I've been told some time ago that Allow Origin accepted only one origin. Try using `*` ?

Comment: i'm trying to configure access for two addresses only not everyone.

Comment: As I told you, I think that Allow Origin only accepts one origin.

Comment: is there no alternative?

Comment: [Maybe you could try this ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains)

Comment: it's not helping

Comment: It looks helpful, even though it's only for Apache. I myself learnt something with it.

Comment: But if you have time to kill, [find your solution here](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-hea)

Comment: A Spring-specific solution for your case is in the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains/32593277#32593277